# Adwords, Python Import Script. MySQL goes fubar

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, google-ads-api

I wrote a Python 2.7 script based on the Python examples from google Adwords on github, installed the MySQL Connector from MySQL Page itself under Connectors.

And started with creating the script, but I am not able to find the bug which is causing that MySQL stops insert data or not even goes into the function.

No error messages, even removed all try and catch. Same.
If you like to check it for yourself: http://pastebin.com/WEQqBNHB

I used 5 Connections, because the functions call each other and it seems like if while is used you need one connection for it seperated.

MySQL Syntax is okay, as phpmyadmin is telling me.

Everything works exept Adgroups_AD/Adgroups_Performance
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that i even need to commit select query's in python.
That fixed the issue. dang.